# R bar chart count data based on dates

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, bar-chart, visualization

I have a data frame consisting of article texts and their specific dates. I want to plot the number of news articles published per month.

How do I:

1. aggregate the articles by their months rather than specific dates
2. plot the count of number of articles published per month in bar chart format using ggplot?

```
articledf <- data.frame(articles = c("on April 3rd","Happening now", "This happened today", "Today, this happened", "Yesterday, a car crashed into a building", "Tomorrow, this will take place"))
articledf$date <- as.Date(c("18/04/2021","21/04/2021","28/05/2021", "30/05/2021","30/05/2021","30/05/2021"), format = "%d/%m/%y")
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use month from the lubridate package.

```
df$month = month(df$date)
ggplot(df, aes(x = month)) + geom_bar()
```